# success callback on resource class action, or on resources promise, which is first?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, promise, angular-resource

Imagine following

`var resource = resourceClass.get(function(data){ 
      console.log("red");
      console.log(data);
});`

`resource.$promise.then(function(data){
        console.log("green"); 
        console.log(data);
});`

Which of these success callbacks will be executed first, red or green? Will it always be the same?

Comment: Most likely `red`, but it depends on how `resourceClass.get` works. The one that is registered first is executed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. A [ngResource `.get` call](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L499) internally does:

```
Resource[name] = function (a1, a2, a3, a4) {
var params = {}, data, success, error;
...
var promise = $http(httpConfig).then(function (response) {
...
promise = promise.then(function (response) {
    var value = responseInterceptor(response);
    (success || noop)(value, response.headers);
     return value;
},responseErrorInterceptor)

value.$promise = promise;
return value;
```

This means that basically, the success callback will *always* run before the $promise `.then`. However, this is implementation detail, I would not rely on it if I were you.

The promise itself chains so you can do:

```
resource.$promise.then(function(data){
    console.log("green"); 
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}).then(function(data){
    console.log("foo",data);
});
```